# Collapse Bootstrap 3 Plugins Conflict Wordpress

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress, wordpress-theming, conflict

to whom it may concern,

I'd like some help working out why a bootstrap collapse link is working but not correctly. It's the blue button below the world map on the left of the test site (link below). It should hide the text below when the button's clicked. But when it's clicked it scrolls to the element it's linked to, rather than collapsing the element.

I realise there's a lot of .js scripts that might be overriding the bootstrap collapse function. Is there something I can add as a snippet to make sure there's no conflict? Below is the link to the test site & a link to show the button that's not acting right.

[Link here - collapse now fixed](http://www.redrocketwebsitedesign.co.uk/test/8612_Hochtief/)

[Image link here](http://www.redrocketwebsitedesign.co.uk/test/8612_test.png)

Thanks in advance :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `html` for the `anchor` includes `href` instead of `data-target` and that is what making it `scroll up`. So change it to `data-target` from `href`.

**Current**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#collapseExample" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                       <!--^^^^Change this-->
```

**Update**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#collapseExample" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                       <!--^^^^^^^^^^^To this-->
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: Hi Guruprasad, thanks I just tried this & it works. I assumed if a link element worked on the Bootstrap guide it would work on mine, I'm not sure why a href doesn't work. But I'm happy it's fixed :-]

Comment: @user3248292.. Can you show the link to the doc you referred where you found this with link element?

Comment: Oh yea.. Well as you were thinking some `js` or `plugin` might have prevented this `action` but it is always good to use `data-target`.. :)